Xbox 360 kinect camera issue with python
I have a problem with the freenect library, so I am using Ubuntu 22.04, and I am trying to run my code, but I can't run it because the code has "import freenect", and I am trying to download that library, but I keep making that error:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement freenect (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for freenect


So can anyone help me?
I tried to import pyfreenect and freenect. I have probably having issue with the Python wrapper for freenect. I guess the freenect. File is missing, but I am not sure.

There is no packages named freenect or pyfreenect on PyPI. Maybe you mean freenect2?
pip install freenect2

Here is their repository: https://github.com/rjw57/freenect2-python

do read their documentation for installation as well, it seems that a simple pip install won't be enough with this library. https://rjw57.github.io/freenect2-python/#installation

This library is for kinect v2 and libfreenect2 is not useful for me I am using libfreenect

can you include more details in your question like the command you used to get this error as well as an example code to help users reading your question
